# Using in_array inside a foreach to filter associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have a JSON array converted to a PHP associative array. I'm attempting to loop through this associative array, and where the key matches a value held in a separate array (`$filter`), I want to echo the `key` and `value` from my associative array.

```
$filter = array("test1", "test");

foreach ($central as $key => $value) {
   $key = str_replace("_", " ", $key); 
   if(in_array('$filter', $key)){
       echo "<ul>".ucwords($key).':' .' '. $value."</ul>";
    }
   else { 
       continue;
   }
}
```

So to recap, if the `$key` of my `$central` associative array is equal to a value in my `$filter` array I want to echo out the values. Else go to the next item in the loop. This code does not work however,

> *syntax error, unexpected '=>'*

Comment: Read the manual about [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) and see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/3933332 (+ Error is not reproducible: https://3v4l.org/B9XhX)

Comment: It would also be useful to see an example of the `$central` array, as replacing `_` with a space may not generate a match to your `$filter` arrays content either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `in_array` function you had to insert the key you are looking for (needle) as first parameter and the array as second parameter.

See [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) for further information.

Here is the code with the correct call to the in_array function.

```
foreach ($central as $key => $value) {
    $key = str_replace("_", " ", $key); 
    if(in_array($key, $filter)){
        echo "<ul>".ucwords($key).':' .' '. $value."</ul>";
    }
}
```

Note that `continue` statement is useless because is at the end of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think you have the "needle" and "haystack" the wrong way round.
Also there is no need for the else statement.

```
foreach ($central as $key => $value) {
   $key = str_replace("_", " ", $key); 
   if(in_array($key, $filter)){
     echo "<ul>".ucwords($key).':' .' '. $value."</ul>";
   }
}
```